# Passing arguments to a Java method

Tags: java, variables, arguments, parameter-passing, containers

I need to pass arguments to a java method `func(String, String...)`.
Problem is I have all the strings I need to pass as arguments, but they are in an `ArrayList` container.

For Example:

```
for(...some condition...)
{
    //the other method returns an ArrayList with different size in each iteration
    ArrayList <String> values = someOtherMethod(); 
    func(values) //values is an ArrayList<String>, containing all the arguments
}
```

I get an error saying that `ArrayList<String>` can't be converted to `String`.
The size of values changes, because the `someOtherMethod` method returns a container with different size each iteration, so I can't pass `values[0], values[1], etc` as arguments.

I'm guessing the `func` wants an X amount of String variables, but I don't know how to convert a container to an X amount of variables when the size of the container isn't constant.

Comment: What's the exact signature of the `func` method?

Comment: Also explaining a little bit about what the `func` method is for might lead to less answers of the guessing type and more higher-quality answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "..." operator accepts arrays, so you could just do the following:

```
ArrayList <String> values = someOtherMethod(); 
func(values.toArray(new String[values.size()]);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a little bit complex as `func` requires one `String` and then an arbitrary number of additional `Strings`:

```
List<String> values = someOtherMethod();
if (values.isEmpty()) {
    // handle special case
} else{
    func(values.get(0), values.subList(1, values.size()).toArray(new String[]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm guessing the func wants an X amount of String variables,

I guess you are looking for **Varargs.**

Change your function signature to accept as

```
public someReturnType func(String... vargs) { }
```

Which takes variable length of args as parameter.

And then inside the method ,you can access them like

```
  for (String currentarg: args) {

   // do something with currentarg
 }
```

As a side note : Available from version 1.5 only.

[Learn more from docs about Varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)